# Listing the SD card files on the Arduino TFT Screen

Tags: arduino

I'm experiencing a problem while trying to list files in an SD card:
I have the following code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <TFT.h>  

#define sd_cs  4
#define lcd_cs 10
#define dc     9
#define rst    8  

TFT TFTscreen = TFT(lcd_cs, dc, rst);

PImage logo;

void intro() {
    TFTscreen.begin();
    TFTscreen.background(255, 255, 255);
    TFTscreen.stroke(0, 0, 255);
    TFTscreen.println();
    TFTscreen.println("Welcome..");
    delay(500);
}


void draw(char *imageName)  {
  TFTscreen.begin();
  TFTscreen.background(255, 255, 255);

  // Load the image file.
  logo = TFTscreen.loadImage(imageName);
  if (!logo.isValid()) {
    Serial.println("error while loading the image");
  }
  if (logo.isValid() == false) {
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("drawing image");

  // draw the image to the screen
  TFTscreen.image(logo, 0, 0);
}  

void initSD() {    
   Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
   if (!SD.begin(sd_cs)) {
        Serial.println("failed!");
        return;
   }
   Serial.println("OK!"); 

}  

void setup() 

    Serial.begin(9600);

    intro();

    initSD();

  draw("2.bmp");
}

void loop() { }
```

The above code works fine, the "Welcome" message is displayed on the screen, followed by the display of the "2.bmp" image as expected. The serial output prints:

```
IniInitializing SD card...OK!
File size: 61496
Image Offset: 54
Header size: 40
Bit Depth: 24
Image size: 128x160
drawing image
```

Now I tried to list the files on the root of the SD card:

```
File root;
void listSD()  {
    root = SD.open("/");
    printDirectory(root);
}

void printDirectory(File dir) {
    while(true) {

        File entry =  dir.openNextFile();
        if (! entry) {
            dir.rewindDirectory();
            break;
        }

        Serial.println(entry.name());
   }
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    intro();

    initSD();
    listSD(); //<- this function here

   draw("2.bmp");
```

}

But I get file not found error, right after the root folder is listed:

```
Initializing SD card...OK!
1.BMP
2.BMP
loadImage: file not found: 2.bmp
error while loading the image
```

Can you please tell me what could be wrong here ? I suspect the `root = SD.open("/");` somehow affects the `TFTscreen.loadImage(imageName);` but I have no idea how.

I'm using an Arduino UNO R3, with a [TFT LCD](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/GTFT) screen, IDE version is 1.5.5.

Answer (score 2):

```
void printDirectory(File dir) {
  //------------------------------------------------------------
  dir.rewindDirectory(); // you need to rewind the the Directory
  //------------------------------------------------------------
  while(true) { 
    File entry =  dir.openNextFile();
    if (! entry) {
      break;
    }          
    Serial.println(entry.name());

  ..etc

  }
}
```

// bug [issue #904](https://code.google.com/p/arduino/issues/detail?id=904)

Comment: I encounter this problem just now and this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this function:

```
void printDirectory(File dir) {
    while(true) {

        File entry =  dir.openNextFile();
        if (! entry) {
            dir.rewindDirectory();
            break;
        }
        else 
            entry.close();  //<-- We need to close the file here

        Serial.println(entry.name());
   }
}
```

The file should be closed so it can be read later ..